# How to render different Language characters correctly on a aspx file

Tags: asp.net

**Problem** I am able to specify how a language should be emphasized, but not able to specify font information. Do I need a specific Font location?

Let me specify what I mean. I would like to have a aspx file that can have multiple different language text (sentences and so on).

So I did the following:

```
<%
string value1 = "日本語を話される場合";
string value2 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value1);
Response.Write(value2);
%>
```

However, the following is generated.

**æ—¥æœ¬èªžã‚’è©±ã•ã‚Œã‚‹å ´åˆ**

I would like it to generate 日本語を話される場合 for mandarin instead of the characters that were generated..

Comment: Welcome to SOF. Can you provide more information?

Comment: @Xaqron: Sorry about that. I would like to have a asp file that has multiple different language text. I am able to generate the Spanish(some characteres I need to locate the html code equivalent) and English fine. However, if I try to render mandarin, random characters are generated. I also tried doing a html file and it still does not render the characters correctly

Comment: Is your file saved in `UTF-8` encoding? (You need a text editor to support that i.e. notepad++). Also your response encoding should be the same type.

Comment: @Xaqron: Can you please elaborate by same type? And provide an example please. I am new to this

Comment: @Xaqron and yes, it is saved in UTF-8 encoding

Comment: @Xaqron: Thank You. I figured out why it was not working

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please consider posting more info on your next question.